# How to call instance method from another instance method of the same class?

Tags: ruby

I'm learning Ruby and I'm trying to develop a blackjack game.

I create a class and here is the GIST

https://gist.github.com/robypez/7288032

my Hand class create a new hand object for a player (or for the dealer)
It's an array, and inside the array every card is defined by an hash with this key :card, :suit, :value

I have a problem with the "compensate_ace_value" method.
This method must use the "ace_number" value returned from the instance method ace_number

How can I call an instance method from another instance method inside a class?

I know that I can define an instance valuable that keep track of my ace number, but i want to know if is possible to call an instance method from another instance method inside a class.

My actual solution is to use the instance variable @ace_number and every time i call the method "receive_card" i call the method "is_ace?" on the card and in the result is true i increment the @ace_number variable.

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

Here is some simple code to answer your subject question of the post.

> How to call instance method from another instance method of the same class?

```
class Foo
  def bar
    11
  end

  def baz
    bar
  end
end

Foo.new.baz # => 11
```